# How can I make a TextField width adapt to his content?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Is there any option that make a TextField adapt to his content?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you currently using constraints in your app?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it manually by adjusting the frame of the textview when a change in it occurs.

```
var text: String = "Some text is just here..."
let size: CGSize = text.size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)])
```

^The code will give you the size needed for the text to be fully displayed and you can resize you textView according to it. //be aware there might be some paddings inside the textview

```
extension String {
    func heightWithConstrainedWidth(width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)

        return boundingBox.height
    }
}
```

^If you need dynamic height (multi-lines) constraining the width will help you with the task.

I'm not completely sure what you are trying to accomplish, but I hope this helps a little.

Comment: I just need to display a textfield that resizes depending on the content. Where do I have to write the first two lines? And what is "text"?

Comment: @A.J. You should implement the UITextFieldDelegate protocol and set your view controller as the delegate of the textField.
Then in one of the delegate methods - shouldChangeCharacterInRange you can monitor the changes as the user types.

Answer (score 0):

Create a oultet for height constraint of textview. After:

```
 textView.delegate = self
 textView.isScrollEnabled = false

 func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        let fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width
        textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        var newFrame = textView.frame
        newFrame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
        heightTextview.constant = newFrame.size.height //update constraint constant with new height
 }
```

textView will change height for fit multiple line content. It works well